# Compress a string to binary, then convert to base 62?

Tags: php, string, compression

I would like to know if I could save some space by compressing small strings of sentences that I have to use base 62 instead of binary.

```
$string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore';

$string = pack("nc*", $string); // Doesn't work

$base62 = gmp_strval(gmp_init($string, 2), 62);
```

I would assume that base 62 would take less space than the ASCII version of the binary.

Comment: What is your charset? I see A-Z, a-z, space, "," - you should be able to use a base lower than 62 so.

Comment: No, because "base 62" (I know base64, but base62 is new to me ^^) has only 62 possible values. A character can have all 256. I you want to compress something, use a compression, not a packer.

Comment: Do you actually mean "ASCII" (which, strictly speaking, is a 7-bit code), or 8-bit bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Without restricting the content, an arbitrary string has 8 bits of data per character, and base62 limits you to slightly under 6 bits per character, so you'll get an **expansion** of around 25% by doing this.

You'll need to use a real compression algorithm (e.g, [`deflate`](http://php.net/gzdeflate)) to compress data.

Answer (score 0):

For longer texts you can use GZip:

```
php > $string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore. Lets make the text even longer. And loinger. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do...';
php > echo strlen($string);                                                     
214
php > echo strlen(base64_encode(gzcompress($string, 9)));
164
```

cf. http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.gzcompress.php